# find shellscript execute command for every file

Tags: macos, finder, find, shell-script

I found "find" command is much faster than "Spotlight" in mac os x
i rather visualize the results with automator with no luck
so I hope geeks around SU will help with solution about that

a shellscript.sh searchphrase executes :

1. create folder on desktop "Results" if not there
2. delete everything on this folder (fresh results)
3. foreach result create a simlink

thank you

Comment: Are you searching for the contents of the file or just the file name?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version with a few improvements.

- Don't include your user name in the script, use `~` to refer to your home directory.
- Store the name of the results directory in a variable. This illustrates how to use a variable in a shell script.
- Make the part that removes the result of a previous search more robust: it won't remove anything that's not a symbolic link.
- The most important: your version would fail with file names containing spaces or some special characters, because the shell does some reparsing of the result of `$(...)` and `$file`. You should **always put variable substitutions in double quotes** (i.e., write `"$file"`). My version works correctly with all file names (except if they contain newlines, but that's inescapable with `locate`).

```
#!/bin/bash
results_dir=~/Desktop/results
mkdir -p "$results_dir"
find "$results_dir" -type l -exec rm {} +
echo "Please enter some input: "
read -r input_variable
locate "$input_variable" | while read -r line; do
  ln -s "$line" "$results_dir/"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

my progress:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /Users/arpecop/Desktop/results/
mkdir /Users/arpecop/Desktop/results/
echo "Please enter some input: "
read input_variable
for file in $(locate "$input_variable")
do
ln -s $file  /Users/arpecop/Desktop/results/
done
```